# Adding legend entry makes all other legend entries diagonal and rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, legend-properties

I have attempted anything I could find but to no avail.

I have replicated my issue using the built in dataset mtcars.
I am making a scatter plot with bubble chart characteristics with ggplot2 in R.
A few things in my code that don't work with this data set are a log scale and forcing the colors of the points, but unless the order of those is a factor I think I can deal with that later.

What happened:

I have to have a 1:1 line, I used geom_abline as it seemed to make the most sense.  I used methods I found from other questions to add the legend to the figure, but when that happens all the other legend entries change shape and orientation.

Ideally I would like to fix this problem and make the dashed line display in a horizontal fashion if possible.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat,wt, size=hp, colour=cyl)) +geom_point()+
   scale_size_area(max_size=5)+
   labs(x="drat", y="wt")
    p+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"), 
         panel.grid.major = element_line(colour= "grey75"), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
         axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"))+
   guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6)))+
   geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed"),show_guide = TRUE)+
   scale_linetype_manual("1:1 line", values = 2)
```

UPDATE: To solve the issue with the diagonal rectangles instead of circle points see Didzis Elferts solution below.  **Still looking for a way to make the legend line horizontal instead of on the diagonal like it is now.** 
Code with Didzis Elferts fix added is below

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat,wt, size=hp, colour=cyl)) +geom_point()+
   scale_size_area(max_size=5)+
   labs(x="drat", y="wt")
    p+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"), 
         panel.grid.major = element_line(colour= "grey75"), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
         axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"))+
   guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6, 
    linetype=0)),size = guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=0)))+
geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1, linetype = "dashed"),
    show_guide = TRUE)+scale_linetype_manual("1:1 line", values = 2)
```

Comment: if I put `linetype="dashed"` **outside** the `aes` and turn `show_guide` to F, then it all appears ok, but of course, the legend of the 1:1 line is gone. I don't know if that's of any help...

Comment: Yeah that's the basic way I have the figure now for at least looking okay. I just really think it is a weird issue, and can see needing to have similar figures in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to remove lines from the colour and size legends is to set `linetype=0` inside `override.aes=` for `colour=` and `size=`

```
 + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6,linetype=0)),
        size = guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=0)))
```

Comment: It definitely works, but how can you make the line dashed? If I apply your solution the line becomes solid...

Comment: Great! That fixed it.  When I put it together with the rest of the code, it looks dashed. Is there a way to change the orientation of the line in the legend icon?

Answer (score 1):

A brute force way to get a horizontal line in your legend would be to add a horizontal line to the plot via `geom_hline` and base your legend off that layer instead of `geom_abline`.

Of course, because you don't actually want a horizontal line in your plot you'd then have to hide it some way.  I came up with two hacky ways to do this.  You could either put the line outside the y variable limits and set `ylim` or you could try to make the line blend into the panel background color.  The gridlines may stop the second option from being reasonable.

Option 1, put `geom_hline` outside of the plot limits:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat,wt, size=hp, colour=cyl)) +
    geom_point()+
    scale_size_area(max_size=5)+
    labs(x="drat", y="wt") + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour= "grey75"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black")) +
    geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1), linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed"), show_guide = TRUE) +
    ylim(1.5, NA) +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6, linetype = 0)),
          size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0))) +
    scale_linetype_manual("1:1 line", values = 2)
```

Option 2, put `geom_hline` behind the other layers and make it white, use `override.aes` to make it black in the legend:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat,wt, size=hp, colour=cyl)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 3.2, linetype = "dashed"), show_guide = TRUE, color = "white") +
    geom_point()+
    scale_size_area(max_size=5)+
    labs(x="drat", y="wt") + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black"), 
         panel.grid.major = element_line(colour= "grey75"), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
         axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black")) +
    geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 1), linetype = "dashed") +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6, linetype = 0)),
          size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
          linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "black"))) +
    scale_linetype_manual("1:1 line", values = 2)
```